# Count distinct value and group by another value in the last 24 hours SQL Redshift

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to do a count of B in the last 24 hours for grouped by date and A.

sample table:

```
|            DATE           |      A      |         B          |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|    2021-12-01 00:00:00    |    John     |      device 1      |
|    2021-12-01 01:00:00    |    Maria    |      device 1      |
|    2021-12-01 01:00:00    |    John     |      device 2      |
|    2021-12-01 02:00:00    |    John     |      device 3      |
|    2021-12-01 02:00:00    |    Maria    |      device 2      |
|    2021-12-03 05:00:00    |    John     |      device 4      |
|    2021-12-03 09:00:00    |    John     |      device 5      |
```

expected output:

```
|            DATE           |      A      |  devices_last_24h  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|    2021-12-01 00:00:00    |    John     |          1         |
|    2021-12-01 01:00:00    |    Maria    |          1         |
|    2021-12-01 01:00:00    |    John     |          2         |
|    2021-12-01 02:00:00    |    John     |          3         |
|    2021-12-01 02:00:00    |    Maria    |          1         |
|    2021-12-03 05:00:00    |    John     |          1         |
|    2021-12-03 09:00:00    |    John     |          2         |
```

im using Redshift database.

Can someone help me please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So this is a bit trick especially to do it so it will run fast.  My first approach would be to self join the table with an inequality condition which works (see below).  However, this creates a loop-join which can be slow if the table in question is very very large.  Otherwise this should work fine.

Set up:

```
create table test (dt timestamp, a varchar(16), b varchar(16));

insert into test values
('2021-12-01 00:00:00','John','device 1'),
('2021-12-01 01:00:00','Maria','device 1'),
('2021-12-01 01:00:00','John','device 2'),
('2021-12-01 02:00:00','John','device 3'),
('2021-12-01 02:00:00','Maria','device 2'),
('2021-12-03 05:00:00','John','device 4'),
('2021-12-03 09:00:00','John','device 5');
```

Query:

```
select t1.dt, t1.a, count(t2.dt) as devices_last_24h
from test t1
join test t2
on t1.a = t2.a and t1.dt between t2.dt and t2.dt + interval '1 day'
group by 1, 2
order by t1.dt;
```

I did a fiddle here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5dd49/8

There are a few edge conditions that you may want to think about that aren't present in your test data.  Like: multiple rows for the same person and timestamp or 2 timestamps exactly 24 hours apart, how should these be counted?

Comment: Hi Bill, thank you for the info.

Yes, that edge case has to be considered.... Actually the table is very large, probably near the million rows

Comment: A million rows isn't going to give Redshift much of an issue.  Large is a relative term.   This process (self joining) should perform relatively well until the intermediate data set (the result of the join) becomes much larger than available memory.  Cluster size, node type, and how many rows, on average, will be counted per person over a 1 day look back.  If this last number is sub-5 you should have no issues.

Comment: im having issues with same name and same device on the same day

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'll need more info as to what the issue is.  Can you recreate the current issue in that sqlfiddle?

Comment: Hi Bill, take a look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8f60f/1/0

I have cases were I have the same device in the same 24 hours, I need to do a unique count of devices in a 24h window.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8f60f/3